# Linux User and Group permissions strategies for DIY Family NAS

Tags: linux, security, permissions, nas, samba

I am quite new to linux, but I've managed to build my own DIY NAS (Odroid CS2, Ubuntu 18.04), set up Samba, SSH etc. and I am now at the stage of access and folder management.

I do understand what `chown` and `chmod` in general do, but I am missing typical strategies for managing permissions in multi-user environment.

**The situation:**
I am the one responsible in my family for the tech stuff, all other family members are pretty careless when it comes to security, but they also won't follow my suggestions for improvement (however, they will ask for help in case of any trouble).

Therefore, I don't mind to much what they do on their own Windows computers, however, I would like to help them securely store and share their files on our NAS.

There's currently one main folder on the NAS:

`/secure/usr/` with a couple of subfolders:

`/01_monika
/02_rebecca
/03_hans
/04_alfred
/05_share`

Each user has a linux user and samba user with the same name (e.g. monika, rebecca, hans, alfred) and there's one group (e.g. samba_users).

**The problem:**
I want all user store their files in their own user directories, but only some subfolders (such as /photos) should be accessible (read-permission) by other users. All other folders/files should ideally be hidden to other family members, or at least not accessible.

Example: Because family members computers may be compromised by viruses and trojans, nobody should be able to read others users private files by default, e.g. `/02_rebecca/documents` is not accessible by user hans. Yet, `/02_rebecca/photos/` should still have read access, because family members often need to share their photos and ideally I don't want them to store all their shared files separately in `/05_share`.

Thank you for any suggestions!

**Additional thoughts:**

- Do symlinks work to get past parent directory permissions, e.g. to allow `samba_users` access subfolder `/photos/` when permissions for parent directory `/hans/photos/` don't allow read access? I've read that symlinks don't work in windows, but Microsoft [says otherwise](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/symbolic-links).
- I am aware I could create subfolders (e.g.) `/01_monika/private/` and `/01_monika/shared/`, for each user. But I would like to avoid this since some of my family members will get confused and put everything in `/shared`

Comment: First note that NFS guides don't directly map to other protocols. NFS is mainly UID-based (client and server have to match), while SMB and SSHFS are mainly account-based (server only cares about login/password).

Comment: Yes, I've just referred to it because of the nogroup usage

Comment: Could you not install the likes of FreeNAS on the ODroid? This will give you plenty of tools for your requirements....

Comment: This would be possible, but I think Ubuntu has already everything that I need on board (full disk encryption, samba, rsync, ssh - I don't really need more, + it comes with odroid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way as explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18095/in-linux-is-write-permission-equivalent-to-execute-for-directories) by user @Gilles:

> Having read or write permission on a directory without execute permission is not useful. Having execute but not read permission is occasionally useful: it allows accessing files only if you know their exact name, a sort of primitive password protection.

That means, setting the execute bit but disallow read on user directories (`rwx--x---`). Then, on subfolders `/photos/`, allow read and execute permissions for group `family` (`rwxr-x---`).

It means that normally, user directories cannot be opened directly by all family members, but knowing that there is a subfolder `/01_monika/photos/`, a user can directly open this particular folder. Then I only need to create shortcuts to these subfolders on people's desktop, or in the main folder on the NAS somewhere.

I knew it would be possible, this is exactly what I need!